# Is it possible to have angular use a different timezone than the browser?

Tags: angularjs, date

Users of our application have to choose the timezone they want to work in. This is because they might exclusively work for customers of some other timezone.

The dates of the aplication are then stored in UTC.

Javascript takes the timezone offset of the browser when displaying utc dates as local dates, which is not what I want.

For displaying dates I have a filter in place. It takes the offset that was applied because of the browser and removes it. Then the offset as defined by the user is applied. This works for displaying values.

A sample might be: The user sits in UTC+03:00 but his setting in the application is for UTC-4:00.
In the database there is a UTC value of 6am. The desired displayvalue is 6-4 = 2am. This is achieved by removing the offset applied because of his browser (-3) and then applying the offset of his settings.

```
            function standardDateFilterInterceptor(date, format, timezone) {
            if (timezone === "agent") {
                if (date !== null && date !== undefined) {
                    var momentDate = moment(date.toString(), ["YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"]);
                    if (momentDate.isValid()) {
                        date = momentDate.toDate();
                        let offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
                        if (offset !== null && offset !== undefined) {
                            offset = offset * 60000 * (-1);
                            const dateWithOffset = new Date(date.getTime() + offset);
                            date = dateWithOffset;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (agentTimeZoneOffset !== null && !angular.isUndefined(agentTimeZoneOffset)) {
                    timezone = agentTimeZoneOffset;
                }

            }
            return originalFilter.apply(this, [date, format, timezone]);
        }
```

For displaying values this is working but I dont find a way to update values. The adjusted value (2am) in the sample would end up in the scope and overwrite the original value of 6am. I can see that when I change the value to 3 and then back to 2. Is there a way to handle this? Like controlling what gets set in the scope when a dom element changes.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a directive that handles the case when the value in the view is updated

Directive

```
app.directive('tzAdapterTime', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (inputValue) {
                var offset = moment(modelCtrl.$modelValue).parseZone().utcOffset();

                return moment(modelCtrl.$modelValue).subtract(offset, 'minute').toDate();
            });

            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                var offset = moment(inputValue).parseZone().utcOffset();
                return moment(inputValue).add(offset, 'minute').toDate();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

View

```
    <input type="datetime-local"  ng-model="article.publish" tz-adapter-time >
```